# Guava SetMultimap not serializable (due to not serializable WrappedSet)

Tags: java, guava

I'm often using java serialization, which is very usefull to store a complete object hierarchy.

When trying to serialize a SetMultimap, I got an exception saying that that [AbstractMultimap.WrappedSet](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMultimap.java) is not serializable.

How do guava users workaround with this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *views* of elements of a multimap (such as the collections returned from `get` methods, the `asMap` view, etc.) are intentionally not serializable. However, it isn't true that a `SetMultimap` implementation would not be serializable because of that. All implementations of `SetMultimap` that Guava provides are in fact serializable... it's just the partial view collections for them that are not.

If you need to serialize one of these collections, you should explicitly copy it to a normal collection:

```
Set<Foo> foo = Sets.newHashSet(multimap.get(someKey));
```

Comment: Most probably my object tree is keeping a reference on one of these views that should be copied. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** So looking at the source of `AbstractMultimap`, the `Map` that is returned is an `AsMap` or `SortedAsMap`, neither of which are serializable. I would suggest creating a new `HashMap` and use the `putAll` method passing in the `Multimap.asMap()` result. `HashMap` is serializable.

```
HashMap myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.putAll(myMultimap.asMap());
```

Comment: Actually putAll(...) copies the content into the Set created by the multimap itself. Moreover, whatever Set implementation is used, it is always wrapped into a WrappedCollection which is definitly not serializable. Since unfortunately HashMultimap is final, one can't override it, so I started copying the code HashMultimap to modify it, but WrappedCollection has some references to private var that can't be reached... So I just added an enhancement query in http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=615

Comment: I didn't say `HashMultimap` but `HashMap`.

Comment: The values in your HashMap will be the Sets created by the multimap, which are not serializable.