# Guava - Can a Multimap be serialized?

Tags: serialization, guava, multimap

I am looking at this API [`ArrayListMultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) which implements the `Serializable` interface. Does that mean I can serialize this object ? Are all Multimap objects serialized ?

Answer (score 9):

The meaning of `Serializable` is always the same: If an object isn't serializable, it can't be serialized. If it is, it may work or not... Especially in case of collections (including maps and multimaps), it depends on their content.

As an example, you can surely serialize `ArrayList<String>` as `ArrayList.class` is serializable and so is each member of the list. OTOH trying to serialize `ArrayList<Object>` may or may not work: If all contained objects are e.g. strings, it will work. If any member is not serializable, you'll get an exception.

> Does it mean I can serialize this object?

If all keys and values are serializable, you can.

> Are all multiMap object serializable?

No, the interface `Multimap` doesn't extend `Serializable`, so there may be non-serializable implementation. Indeed, you can get such an instance via e.g. `Multimaps.filterEntries`.

Comment: I agree with maartinus. Since I am using ArralyListMultiMap (which implements Serializable) and key and value in my case are String I should be able to Serialized.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayListMultimap` and `HashMultimap` are `Serializable` BUT the `Collection` views (in `asMap()` for example) are not.

This problem is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488394/guava-setmultimap-not-serializable-due-to-not-serializable-wrappedset):

To use the map returned by `asMap()`, you can re-create a new map and wrap the Multimap `Collection` views into other collections (for example a `Set`), that will make the new map `Serializable`:

```
Multimap<MyClass, MyOtherClass> myMultiMap = HashMultimap.create();
// ... build your multimap
Map<MyClass, Set<MyOtherClass>> map = myMultiMap.asMap().entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap( 
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        (entry) -> ImmutableSet.copyOf(entry.getValue()) 
    ));
```

Or java 7 compliant code:

```
Multimap<MyClass, MyOtherClass> myMultiMap = HashMultimap.create();
// ... build your multimap
Map<MyClass, Set<MyOtherClass>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
for (Map.Entry<MyClass, Collection<MyOtherClass>> entry : 
myMultiMap.asMap().entrySet()) {
    map.put(entry.getKey(), ImmutableSet.copyOf(entry.getValue()));
}
```